# Cannot run Windows XP from GRUB (returns to GRUB)

Tags: grub2, dual-boot

GRUB had an error, but by using [Boot repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) I fixed it.

[Here is the boot info script output.](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1370085/)

I have the system selection screen in violet, but I cannot run Windows XP. Only Ubuntu.
When I press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to start Windows, the screen turns black and it returns automatically to the system selection screen.

Answer (score 0):

hy i also tried it like u and i got windows working

i also have asked a question but answersers where poor - if sb answeres here also - pls relink it

i think its in important topic

i tried also this ways - maybe one is for you helpfull what i tried so far

tags: testdisk,linuxreader,...

http://vanceance.blogspot.co.at/2012/11/testdisk-on-my-pc.html

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Answers which are little more than links are unsatisfactory, as they can be susceptible to link rot. Please edit your answer to summarize the main points from your link so others can follow it without having to leave the page. Thanks!