# How to remove the Ubuntu menu of Windows Boot Manager?

Tags: dual-boot, windows

I have an ASUS K55VM and it came with DOS, and then Windows 7 was installed. I am planning to install Ubuntu on it. My computer had 4 partitions: 240GB, 230GB, 230GB, and 230GB, and I changed this to 5 partitions: 243GB, 230GB, 230GB, 150GB, and 80GB. I installed Ubuntu 12.04 to the 80GB partition through a USB flash drive. It installed fine, however the problem is during the Boot option in Windows Boot Manager. When I choose Ubuntu, this what is displayed:

```
Windows failed to start. A recent hardware or software change might be the cause. To fix the problem:

 1. Insert your Windows installation disc and restart your computer. 
 2. Choose your language settings, and then click "Next," 
 3. Click "Repair your computer."
If you don't have this disc, contact your system administrator or computer manufacturer for assistance. 

 File: \ubuntu\winboot\wubildr.mbr 
 Status: 0xc000000e 
 Info: The selected entry could not be loaded because the application is missing or corrupt.
```

I tried to change the boot option for the OS and made Ubuntu as my first option. It worked, however Windows 7 does not show up in GRUB. In this fear I did the following:

1. Restarted my PC changed boot option 1 to Windows.
2. Formatted the drive to which Ubuntu was installed (80GB one) through Windows.
3. Restarted again.

The problem persists. Windows Boot Manager still shows Ubuntu, and when I choose this it gives two lines one like: `grub rescue>`, but my Windows 7 is working perfectly fine.

Now I want a solution to remove Ubuntu from the Windows boot option and reinstall completely.

Comment: A disk can only have a maximum of 4 partitions

Answer (score 1):

You need to use EasyBcd.

http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/OS-Enhancements/EasyBCD.shtml

EasyBCD runs on Windows and modifies the Windows Boot Configuration Data (BCD).

EasyBCD has a number of bootloader-related features that can be used to repair and configure the bootloader.

From the Manage Bootloader section of EasyBCD, it is possible to switch between the Windows 7 and Windows 8 bootloaders from within Windows by simply clicking a button

Answer (score 0):

Use windows 7 disk and do a startup repair. You will find it any windows 7 forum.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your last question correctly, you want to uninstall ubuntu?

Just enter your Live CD/USB and format that partition.

As I've the same problems that you (and many others) had, here are some links that might contain other answers that could help

Mine: 
[Can't boot in Ubuntu after windows upgrade](https://askubuntu.com/questions/219248/cant-boot-in-ubuntu-after-windows-upgrade)

Another question:
[Cannot run Windows XP from GRUB (returns to GRUB)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/219307/cannot-run-one-of-two-os)

What I tried so far, maybe it can also help you:
http://vanceance.blogspot.co.at/2012/11/testdisk-on-my-pc.html